# C# Refit Deserialize False to Null when expecting Class

Tags: c#, json, .net, json-deserialization, refit

Here are 2 json response examples received when logging in...

For the successful response, payload is a class with id and name

```
{
    "merchant": "test123",
    "payload": {
        "id": "1234",
        "name": "Test"
    },
    "code": "100",
    "message": "Request successfully executed"
}
```

...but if the response is unsuccessful I receive the following...

```
{
    "merchant": "test123",
    "payload": false,
    "code": "105",
    "message": "Invalid username or password!"
}
```

I have no control over receiving **"payload": false**. Ideally this would be **"payload": null**.

How can I change the **"payload": false** to **"payload": null** when deserializing the response? Currently getting an exception error at runtime. Using C# and refit.

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Response;

public class ResponseRoot
{
    public string Merchant { get; set; }
    //the value received in the json response needs to become null if the value is false?
    public ResponsePayload? Payload { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public class ResponsePayload
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create Custom Converter that will convert `bool` to `null`. Start here, and come back if you have additional questions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to

Comment: *Currently getting an exception error at runtime.* -- might you please [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?  It would also help us to help you if you would share how you are configuring and calling Refit.  From your question's tags it would appear you are using `SystemTextJsonContentSerializer`, can you confirm and share how you are configuring it?  Finally, is your server returning an error code when `"payload"` is `false`?

Comment: @Felix that's what I needed. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I used this link to solve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60634410/deserialize-false-as-null-system-text-json

Answer (score 0):

you can parse at first

```
    var jObj = JsonObject.Parse(json);
    if (jObj["payload"].ToString() == "false") jObj["payload"] = null;

    ResponseRoot rb = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseRoot>(jObj, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    });
```

if you have some time and desire you can wrap this code in a function or in a custom json converter.

Comment: Hi Serge. Thanks for the suggestion, but do you know if this is possible using refit? Thx

Comment: Try to use JObject class instead of  ResponseRoot and let me know if it works